# How to create custom module for admin area in drupal 8

Tags: views, 8

Sorry if this question is so basic, I'm new about drupal.

So far which I know, we can create custom module or page in drupal 8 so we can access it with http://www.oursite.com/custompage.

What I need? Is possible to create custom module or page which can show in admin area? In this case, I want to sync a lot of accounts from another system/web app to my drupal site so I don't need to create manually using "people menu" in admin area. Or is there any best way to do that?

Can anyone provide a helpful articles to accomplish this? Help would so appreciated.

Comment: What are you asking - how to have a module show up in admin area or how to import users from another site?

Comment: Main question is "how to have a module show up in admin area". With the module I will use to sync data from other applications to drupal site

Answer (score 2):

> Main question is "how to have a module show up in admin area".

1. Create your custom module
2. Create your custom route in the "your_module.routing.yml" - file

Example:

```
your_module.admin_settings:
  path: '/admin/config/your_module/import'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\your_module\Form\ImportForm'
    _title: 'Import XYZ'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site configuration'
```

3. Define the link in the "your_module.links.menu.yml" - file

Example:

```
entity.your_module.admin:
  title: 'Import XYZ'
  route_name: your_module.admin_settings
  description: 'Import XYZ'
  parent: system.admin_config_system
  weight: 100
```

... thats it!
In step 3 this line is the important part:

```
parent: system.admin_config_system
```

If you need a menu entry in "structure" you can use:

```
parent: system.admin_structure
```

Just read other xyz.links.menu.yml - files to find different parent-path.